# Liferay 7 and Vaadin 8: Vaadin Shared is not active

Tags: java, liferay, vaadin, portlet, vaadin8

I'm try to install a module with a vaadin portlet. When the bundle started throws the following exception.

Does any one knows how to check if Vaadin Liferay Integration is active? or my module needs to activate atuomatically?

thanks

```
2018-08-30 17:45:07.745 INFO  [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: b06cd3dd-72ac-0018-1cb3-ebc69224d879][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.smart.services.vaadin.test_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT [979]
2018-08-30 17:45:07.755 ERROR [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: b06cd3dd-72ac-0018-1cb3-ebc69224d879][com_smart_services_vaadin_test:97] [com.vaadin.osgi.liferay.VaadinPortletProvider(3827)] The activate method has thrown an exception 
com.vaadin.osgi.resources.OsgiVaadinResources$ResourceBundleInactiveException: Vaadin Shared is not active!
    at com.vaadin.osgi.resources.OsgiVaadinResources.getService(OsgiVaadinResources.java:66)
    at com.vaadin.osgi.liferay.VaadinPortletProvider.activate(VaadinPortletProvider.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:224)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:39)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:617)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:501)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:302)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:294)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createImplementationObject(SingleComponentManager.java:297)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createComponent(SingleComponentManager.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:906)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getServiceInternal(SingleComponentManager.java:879)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:748)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enableInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:674)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:429)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ConfigurableComponentHolder.enableComponents(ConfigurableComponentHolder.java:657)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialEnable(BundleComponentActivator.java:341)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:403)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.access$200(Activator.java:54)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator$ScrExtension.start(Activator.java:278)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:482)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.applyDelta(ModuleContainer.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.resolveAndApply(ModuleContainer.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.resolve(ModuleContainer.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.refresh(ModuleContainer.java:955)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerWiring.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerWiring.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

I added part of my code.

My pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>PruebaLiferay7-modules</artifactId>
        <groupId>PruebaLiferay7</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.smart.services.vaadin.portlet.reports.active.agent</groupId>
    <artifactId>fielder-tracking-osgi-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fielder</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-fielder</artifactId>
            <version>3.1-migration</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.portal.kernel</artifactId>
            <version>3.26.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.util.taglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.cmpn</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-liferay-integration</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-osgi-integration</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/META-INF/resources/**/.sass-cache/</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>biz.aQute.bndlib</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
                        <artifactId>com.liferay.ant.bnd</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.54</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My bdn.bnd

```
Bundle-Name: fielder-tracking-osgi-test
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.smart.services.vaadin.test
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Import-Package: !com.liferay.portal.kernel.util,\
!com.google.*,\
!com.smart.service.api.*,\
!com.smart.service.portal.*,\
!com.vaadin.*,\
!com.googlecode.gentyref.*,\
!com.ibm.icu.text.*,\
!com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.*,\
!com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.*,\
!com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.*,\
!com.squareup.okhttp.*,\
!com.sun.mail.util.*,\
!com.sun.xml.fastinfoset.sax.*,\
!com.sun.xml.fastinfoset.stax.*,\
!com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.style.*,\
!com.vaadin.data.util.converter.*,\
!com.vaadin.sass.internal.*,\
!com.vaadin.server.data.*,\
!elemental.*,\
!javax.inject.*,\
!libcore.io.*,\
!lombok.*,\
!okio.*,\
!org.antlr.stringtemplate.*,\
!com.beust.jcommander.*,\
!com.conversantmedia.*,\
!com.fasterxml.jackson.*,\
!com.ibm.uvm.*,\
!com.lmax.*,\
!com.sun.*,\
!javax.*,\
!org.apache.*,\
!org.atmosphere.*,\
!org.checkerframework.*,\
!org.fusesource.*,\
!org.jctools.*,\
!org.joda.*,\
!org.json.*,\
!org.jsoup.*,\
!org.jvnet.*,\
!org.zeromq.*,\
!scala.*,\
*
Export-Package: com.smart.services.vaadin.portlet.reports.active.agent.constants}
-jsp: *.jsp,*.jspf
-plugin.jsp: com.liferay.ant.bnd.jsp.JspAnalyzerPlugin
-plugin.resourcebundle: com.liferay.ant.bnd.resource.bundle.ResourceBundleLoaderAnalyzerPlugin
-plugin.sass: com.liferay.ant.bnd.sass.SassAnalyzerPlugin
-sass: *
-includeresource: api-fielder-3.1-migration.jar, fielder-util-api-3.1-migration.jar,\

Bundle-ClassPath:\
  .,\
  api-fielder-3.1-migration.jar.jar,\
  fielder-util-api-3.1-migration.jar,\
  portlet-api.jar,\
```

My vaadin portlet:

```
@Component(service = UI.class, property = { "com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.fielder",
        "javax.portlet.name=" + PortletPortletKeys.Portlet, "javax.portlet.display-name=Fielder Tutorial Portlet",
        "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=power-user,user",
        "com.vaadin.osgi.liferay.portlet-ui=true" }, scope = ServiceScope.PROTOTYPE)

public class ReportServiceAgentPortlet extends UI {

    /** Defines serial version UID. */
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
    /** Class logger. */
    private static final Logger LOGGER              = LogManager.getLogger(ReportServiceAgentPortlet.class);
...
```

Comment: is that an OSGi Portlet (e.g. `@Component`) or a WAR style portlet (e.g. does it have a portlet.xml)? Please add code to make it a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And what *exact* version of Liferay and Vaadin are you using? add minor release numbers as well.

Comment: Yes, its a OSGI Portlet, I'm using Liferay 7.1 and Vaadin 8.5.1.
I added a part of my code below.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is described in detail [here](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/10220).

The fix has been included in Vaadin 8.9 and newer versions, so today the easiest way is just update Vaadin version.

For legacy, I have developed [a fix](https://github.com/ctliv/osgi-bundles/tree/master/vaadin-liferay-integration-fix) that simply waits until Vaadin Shared is active before completing Vaadin Liferay Integration startup. This solves the issue.

Just clone the fix, update Vaadin version and perform a maven build.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I downloaded the fix for vaadin integration, I build it with the vaadin 8.5.1 and the uploaded in the Liferay App Manager. but I still have the issue. So I downladed the https://github.com/ctliv/vaadin-portlet-sample to try to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I updated the pom vaadin-portley-sample to use vaadin 8.5.1 and liferay kernel 3.26.0 and osgi version 7.0.0. The bundle compile its fine, then I upload de jar to Liferay and when I tried to Activated the app throws the error:
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception; version="[7.4.0,8.0.0)"_ [Sanitized]
In the pom I have
<import.package>
   ...
   com.liferay.portal.*,
   com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.*; version="[7.4.0,8.0.0)",

Comment: Hello. Vaadin-portlet-sample was developed before Liferay 7.1 and import package versioning was not correct. Now it is fixed (tested with Vaadin 8.2.0).
Regarding Vaadin-liferay-integration-fix, I think you are experiencing a different issue. Vaadin Server (version 8.5.1 as well) imports package com.liferay.portal.kernel.util with version "[7.0,8)" but Liferay 7.1 exports version 8.0.0 of this package. So Vaadin Server does not start (and so Vaadin Liferay Integration). You should build and use this fix for Vaadin Server: https://github.com/ctliv/osgi-bundles/tree/master/vaadin-server-fix

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I deployed the sample portlet in Liferay 7.0 and vaadin 8.5.1 and I don't have the errors. In the bnd file I added -includeresource: lib/com.liferay.portal.kernel.jar=com.liferay.portal.kernel-[0-9]*.jar;lib:=true,\

Bundle-ClassPath:\
  .,\
  lib/com.liferay.portal.kernel.jar,\
Seems like Liferay 7.1 have some issues with vaadin
Thanks, any way

Comment: You do not have to include any liferay jar in your bundle. This creates a collision with existing Liferay libs. I confirm that Vaadin works on Liferay 7.1, but Vaadin Server (up to 8.5.1)  needs the fix I made (and Vaadin Liferay Integration, too). I'll see if I can produce a more detailed guide, but I'll need time, anyway.

Comment: thank for the answer, you are right, I removed the import portal.kernel package. While liferay 7.1 and vaadin 8.5.1 will be stable, I decided to keep Liferay 7.0

Comment: Since Liferay 7.1, if you make sure you deploy all the vaadin dependencies except for vaadin-liferay-integration-8.x.x.jar and let them start, then deploy vaadin-liferay-integration-8.x.x.jar you will not get the error.

Answer (score 0):

maybe someone is still having this problem and is looking for an answer...
from my experience it is fixed with Vaadin 8.9.0