# Liferay7 and Vaadin8 install ProoTools Vaadin Chart 4.0.5

Tags: liferay, vaadin, liferay-7, vaadin8

I recently migrated to Liferay 7.0, I'm trying to install Vaadin Charts but I do not have success.
I installed the follow jar in the App Manager
 vaadin-charts-4.0.5.jar, jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar, jackson-core-2.5.1.jar, jackson-databind-2.5.2.jar

then when I access to my portlet that use Chart component throws an excepcion :

```
2018-09-12 03:11:05.023 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-10][PortletServlet:112] javax.portlet.PortletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Series
javax.portlet.PortletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Series
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinPortlet.handleRequest(VaadinPortlet.java:552)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinPortlet.serveResource(VaadinPortlet.java:633)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:122)
    at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:85)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:40)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:532)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeResource(InvokerPortletImpl.java:635)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.serveResource(InvokerPortletImpl.java:471)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.serveResource(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:303)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._serveResource(PortletContainerImpl.java:848)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.serveResource(PortletContainerImpl.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.serveResource(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:173)
```

So I installed the vaadin-charts-model-4.0.5.jar in the App Manager, but the module of vaadin-chart-model has not been activated and does not appear in the app Managed installed.

How can I use the ProoTools Vaadin Chart ?

Comment: I'm not working with Vaadin, but recently [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52111504) was discussed here. You might want to check if it applies to your situation as well.

Comment: Thanks @OlafKock , but its a differente issue, in the issue that you comment I posted that was fixed changed the liferay version, I deploy vaadin portlets succefully, but now I want to integrate ProTools from Vaadin and I have the issue mentioned above.

Comment: oops - sorry. If I had seen that it was your own question, I wouldn't have pointed this one out. Missed that.